# Can you move a variable to a higher scope in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Just started learning Rust and the following snippet is for a Codewars training I am trying to solve.
I am trying to move a variable outside the `for num in nums { }` scope. The value does not live long enough, which I can understand. But how to fix it? Cloning did not work.

```
fn is_sum_of_cubes(s: &str) -> String {
  let nums = s.split(|x: char| !x.is_numeric())
              .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
              .collect::<Vec<_>>();

let mut s: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
  
  for num in nums {
    let ch = num.chars()
                .collect::<Vec<char>>();
    
    let chunk = ch.chunks(3)
                  .map(|c| c.iter().collect::<String>())
                  .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                  .join(" ");
    
    let spl = chunk.split_ascii_whitespace()
                   .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("spl: {:?}", &spl);
    s = spl.clone();
  }
  
  println!("chunks: {:?}", s);

  "Oeps".to_owned()
}
```

```
Compiling rust v0.1.0 (/Users/m.h.doornekamp/tmp/rust)
error[E0597]: `chunk` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:18:15
   |
18 |     let spl = chunk.split_ascii_whitespace()
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
23 |   }
   |   - `chunk` dropped here while still borrowed
24 |   
25 |   println!("chunks: {:?}", s);
   |                            - borrow later used here
```

Comment: The variable `Chunks` is a `String`. The `spl` is a reference to a portion of the string to it is only valid as long as the string it points to is valid. The solution is to convert each part to it's own string.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your advice and got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `s` as vector of `String` instead of string slices. `String` is an owned data type whereas string slices are references.

Do the below two changes in your code and it should be fine.

```
let mut s: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
```

then inside the loop -

```
s = chunk.split_ascii_whitespace().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Also, instead of `.join(" ")` and then `.split_ascii_whitespace()` you can probably combine those two steps. That would be another nicer optimization.

Comment: Allocating, then stomping seems wasteful. Why not just append to `s`?

Comment: Yes, I would do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the advice. It was very helpful. This is how I solved it.

```
fn is_sum_of_cubes(s: &str) -> String {
  // extract the numbers from string slice s
  let nums = s.split(|x: char| !x.is_numeric())
              .filter(|x| !x.is_empty())
              .collect::<Vec<_>>();

  // split the numbers in groups of 3 digits
  let mut arr: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
  
  for num in &nums {
    // make chunks of 3 digits
    let chunk = num.chars()
                   .collect::<Vec<char>>()
                   .chunks(3)
                   .map(|c| c.iter().collect::<String>())
                   .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                   .join(" ");
    
    // add each chunk to the array
    arr.append(&mut chunk.split_ascii_whitespace()
                         .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                         .iter()
                         .map(|x| x.to_string())
                         .collect());
  }
  
  println!("nums: {:?}", &nums);
  println!("chunks: {:?}", &arr);

  "Oeps".to_owned()
}
```